# Is this C# await superfluous?

Tags: c#, ajax, multithreading, async-await

I understand threading to a certain extent, but in practice I have little experience. In looking at this code that I am maintaining, it seems that the AWAIT provides no benefit. All calls to this method are via AJAX and happen only when a user clicks an export link. Since the method does nothing else, I don't see any advantage to AWAIT and instead imagine that it actually introduces some overhead. I also believe that all other users clicking export would be entering this method as their own thread, right? So this might only be useful if a single user clicked export many times, quickly? Thank you.

```
[PreventLogging]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetActivityReportCallsAsync([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await GetAllCallsAsync();
            return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return JsonShowMessage(false, ServerMessageType.Error, exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How else do you expect to obtain *result*?

Comment: @HansPassant: While true, the OP acknowledges only a minimal understanding of threading.  Given that context, perhaps a little more explanation...

Comment: The alternative is to explicitly get the value of the Task which is clunkier. However await/async gives a huge benefit, in which it's implemented as a continuation, meaning that your thread actually gets freed up while the asynchronous call is executing.

Comment: You can go right ahead and write the same code without the `await`  If you find that the code is just as easy to work with, then you may decide its superfluous here.  if you find that it's a lot more work to try to accomplish this without `await`, then it's not superfluous.

Answer (score 8):

> it seems that the AWAIT provides no benefit

You may want to take a look at my [`async` on ASP.NET MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). In it, I enumerate a number of common misconceptions about what `async` will or won't do for your requests.

In summary, `async`/`await` on ASP.NET is for *scalability*, and assumes that you *already have a scalable backend*. It won't make any *individual* request run faster, or return earlier, or anything like that.